# If $4x \le g(x) \le 2x^4 − 2x^2 + 4$ for all x, evaluate $\lim_{x \to 1} g(x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

If $4x \le g(x) \le 2x^4 − 2x^2 + 4$ for all x, evaluate $\lim_{x \to 1} g(x)$

How do you solve this? I'm having trouble

Comment: Make sure I parsed your title correctly.

Comment: Seems correct to me that's how I had interpreted it at first.

Answer (score 2):

This is something called the squeeze theorem so you'll have to calculate the limit  of $4x$ and $2x^4-2x^2+4$ which obviously both give $4$ as $x$ tends to $1$ so therefore the limit of $g(x)$ as $x$ tends to $1$ is $4$.